# How do I redefine SBT's test task?

Tags: scala, testing, sbt, redefinition

In my current environment, `sbt test` doesn't work. I would like to make sbt print "This doesn't work, do the following instead: [...]" until we get `sbt test` sorted out. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
test := throw new MessageOnlyException("this does not work")
```

You really should have read the sbt docs for this.